# Deciding whether a function $f$, defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, is Lebesgue-integrable over two sets

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I want to decide  on which of the following sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ the function $f(x, y) = e^{-x y} sin(x)$ is Lebesgue-integrable:

$$(i) A = [0, R] \times [0, \infty], R > 0;\space\space\space\space (ii) A = [0, \infty)^2 $$

Now, I believe (although I'm note entirely sure) it's sufficient to show that (at least) one of the integrals $\int_{[0, \infty]} ( \int_{[0, R]} |f(x, y)| dx) dy$ or $\int_{[0, R]} ( \int_{[0, \infty]} |f(x, y)| dy) dx$ exists and is $< \infty$? (Which, I believe, is a consequence out of Tonelli and Fubini?)

So therefore, if we consider $\int_{[0, R]} ( \int_{[0, \infty]} |f(x, y)| dy) dx = \int_{[0, R]} ( \int_{[0, \infty]} |\frac{sin(x)}{e^{xy}}| dy) dx = \int_{[0, R]} \frac{|sin(x)|}{x} dx$ (according to [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%5Cinfty+%7Csin%28x%29%2F%28e%5E%28x*y%29%29%7C+dy), will try to manually check this later on), which exists for all $R > 0$, can we already say that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable over the set $A$ given in $(i)$?

If I suspect that $f$ isn't Lebesgue-integrable over the set $A$, given in (ii), could I show that by showing that neither of the two iterated integrals exist and are $< \infty$?

If we consider that $\int_{[0, \infty)} ( \int_{[0, \infty)} |\frac{sin(x)}{e^{xy}}| dy) dx = \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{|sin(x)|}{x} dx$, which I believe doesn't exist, would I need to check the other iterated integral aswell, or is it (according to Fubini's theorem) already enough to disprove that one of the integrals is $< \infty$?

I'm still relatively confused about the existence of Lebesgue integrals in multiple dimensions, and how to check if they *do* exist. Is there an easier or nicer way to see whether or not these two integrals exist?

Comment: For (ii): If $f(x,y)$ where integrable, then the integral of $|f(x,y)|$ over $A$ should be finite, independent of the order of integration. But..

Comment: @TheOscillator but since one order of integration already gives me an integral that's not $< \infty$, that means $f$ isn't integrable over $A$ in (ii), does it?